# How can I create immutable DTOs using Jackson but without annotions?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, immutability

Jackson can deserialize JSON data into immutable objects. But by default the constructor or static factory method parameters have to be specified either using `@JsonProperty` or using `@ConstructorProperties`. How can I configure Jackson and the compiler so that these annotations are not needed? And how do I best configure these when using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

When serializing Java 17's records no further steps are needed because records store the names of their components. But when serializing normal classes three configurations are needed:

- The immutable DTO needs to be compiled with javac's `-parameters` flag.
- The ParameterNamesModule needs to be needs to be registered with Jackson's ObjectMapper
- A special case is when the DTO construct takes a single structured type (e.g. a List or Map). In this case Jackson uses a so called "delegating" mode which is not wanted in this case. This can be changed by configuring the ObjectMapper: `mapper.setConstructorDetector(USE_PROPERTIES_BASED)`. This is supported since [Jackson 2.12](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1498).

In Spring Boot the first two settings are the default thus no changes are needed. The third configuration can be done by providing a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean:

```
@Bean public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer() {
  return builder -> builder.postConfigurer(mapper -> mapper.setConstructorDetector(USE_PROPERTIES_BASED));
}
```